What is the first appearance of Will Waring's signature pineapple-in-a-shot running gag?
Will Waring is one of the directors for the Stargate series, and his signature for each episode he directs is a pineapple hidden somewhere in the episode in clear view.
According to https://screenrant.com/stargate-running-gags/ this started after he accidentally left a pineapple clearly visible in the back of a car in an earlier non-Stargate production when he started as a cameraman.
What production was this, and is there a video or a screencap of this pineapple available somewhere?

TIL (today I learned)                     .

@JasonPSallinger : the 2013 movie? isn't that (by far) after WW worked on SG1?
